# Create Dynamic Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

i just wanted to create a Dynamic Object in JS, but the Object only saves the last Element of the foor loop. Heres my Code :

```
for(var i = 0; i < req.session.userObjekt.length; i++) {
  var userObjekt = {
    [req.session.userObjekt[i].User]: {
      Data : req.session.userObjekt[i].Data, 
      Admin: req.session.userObjekt[i].Admin
    }
  };
}
```

When i output in the for loop i get the correct result (7 Users + Properties) 
When i output out of the for loop, i only get the last User + Properties.

How to save all Elements from the for loop in my Object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are creating a new userObjekt each time and it seems it is replacing all the previous ones and last one is contained.

Comment: Are you looping in the same array and assigning data from same array to same array with a syntax issue.

Comment: Yes, i just realized im creating the same Objekt over and over again. sorry for molesting everybody with my stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you assign to your `userObjekt` a new object in each iteration. Move out your object declaration from the `for` loop body

```
var userObjekt = { };

for(var i = 0; i < req.session.userObjekt.length; i++) {

  userObjekt[req.session.userObjekt[i].User] = {
      Data : req.session.userObjekt[i].Data, 
      Admin: req.session.userObjekt[i].Admin
  };

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `userObjekt` be an array `var userObjekt = [];`

Comment: It depends on his logic. Actually I think you are right, but in his example he intend to use a new propertiy for each object and can access his objects via `User`

Comment: i just realized what a stupid mistake i made!
Code works perfectly, thank you very much!
will mark this answer als "solved"

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array outside of loop and just push the objects in it later on you can use the declared and filled array:

```js
var objektArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<req.session.userObjekt.length; i++) {
  var userObjekt = {
    [req.session.userObjekt[i].User]: {
      Data : req.session.userObjekt[i].Data, 
      Admin: req.session.userObjekt[i].Admin
    }, 
  };
  objektArr.push(userObjekt);
}

console.log(objektArr);
```